# I can't debug a library in Android-Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am having a little problem to debug my library in android-studio, when i enter in that, i receive the message: 'Decompiled .class file, bytecode version 51.0 (Java 7)'. Because of it i ain't able to receive any value of the debug in watch variables.

In some little search's in internet i saw that it can be a problem of version, because of it follow my screen of the File -> Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> Android SDK -> SDK Platform

[image]

If someone could help me i would be quite grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider downloading the source package of the jar file that the decompiled class is on. Usually Itellij suggest to download the source for you

Comment: He suggest, but don't solve nothing. Can be a idiot questio, but how i know with or how i download this source package? Is the 51.0?

Comment: Which class is missing the source?

Comment: I don't know really, he just give me the message: 'Decompiled .class file, bytecode version 51.0 (Java 7)'. And don't let me see the information of the variables.